# Ecognition project can't be saved

Tags: ecognition

I run a project in ecognition but always get a reminder of error when saving it. The error message is:

```
Error while saving project file 'L:\projects\New Project.dpr'
```

Comment: What exactly is the text of the error?

Comment: Error while saving project file 'L:\projects\New Project. dpr'

Comment: Can you create other files to L:\projects\ ?

Comment: No, i can't save any, either created new ones, or modified old ones. And i checked disk storage, which is enough

Comment: I added the error message to the question (comments can be deleted or cleaned up. There's a space before the file extension. That's a transcription error, right?

Comment: Yes there is a space. That's exactly what shows on my project.  Could you please tell me what results in this reminder? How to solve it?